# How do I disable logging the data returned from a BlazeDS call when Debug level logging is enabled?

Tags: apache-flex, logging, blazeds

Based on [this guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=services_logging_3.html), I have enabled debug level logging and also enabled date, time, level and category logging.

This works great, except now I am seeing all my data that's returned being logged. Is there a way to disable this? I would still like to see the calls logged. I've tried info level, but that turns off request logging.

Answer (score 0):

Use filtering as mentioned on that link.